# MIN (DATE) when date is string Hive

Tags: date, hive

I need a min value for a date but when I use min(date) this function doesn't work because for example 2015-5-10 is less than 2015-5-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting it to date.
 `MIN (TO_DATE( CONCAT ( yourdate , '00:00:00' ) ) )`

You may also try this to cast the char to date if the above does not work . Then apply `min`

```
cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(yourdate , 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) as date)
```